# How to get specific data of particular city?

Tags: python, controller, odoo, odoo-11

I have list of cities in database and want to show their specific data in web controllers.
Here, Attach the screenshot and the code which i used.

**Controllerrs.py file**

```
from odoo import http

class CurrentWeather(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/current_weather/', auth='public', website='True')
    def index(self, **kw):
        location = http.request.env['weather_location.weather_location']
        return http.request.render('current_weather.index', {
            'locations': location.search([])
            })

    @http.route('/current_weather/condition', auth='public', website='True')
    def index_current_condition(self, **kw):
        weather_condition = http.request.env['current_weather.current_weather']
        return http.request.render('current_weather.index_condition', {
            'weather_conditions': weather_condition.search([])
            })
```

**Template.xml file**

```
        <template id="index">
        <t t-call="website.layout">
            <t t-set="title">Locations</t>
            <div class="oe_structure">
                <div class="container">
                    <t t-foreach="locations" t-as="location">
                        <p>
                            <a t-attf-href="/current_weather/condition">
                            <center><t t-esc="location.name"/></center>
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </t>

                </div>
            </div>
        </t>
    </template>
```

[image]
When click on mumbai only data of mumbai will show how to do that?
Currently, data shown in all cities are same.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the code but give me the some solution instead of indentation sir@Vadim Kotov

Answer (score 0):

In your controller `index_current_condition` you need to think of a way to filter the `weather_condition` based on the city clicked on. This can be done via the [`search` method of the ORM API](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/online/reference/orm.html#common-orm-methods).

With `weather_condition.search([])` you are returning **all** records found in your model when passing a blank list. So here you need to use something along the lines of `weather_condition.search([('city', '=', current_city)])`, where `city` needs to be a field in your model `current_weather.current_weather` (and should be linked to your other model `weather_location.weather_location`) and `current_city` must be somehow dynamically passed to the controller.